# Hide the 'Overwriting extension' warning when debugging and running extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there anyway I can **hide** this warning message when testing my extensions?

[image: Overwriting extension .../.vscode-insiders/extensions/nodecommands-0.3.0 with h:/VsCodeAddon/nodecommands.[1]]

The message says:

> *[path]* Overwriting extension *[extensionPath]* with *[tempExtensionPath]*

---

As "default", I am passing the `extensionDevelopmentPath` argument in **launch.json**:

### launch.json

```json
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/out"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not currently possible, according to this open vscode issue:

[Do Not Show for overwriting extension message](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/62316)

A Microsoft employee responded:

> This request looks sense to me. I am planning to add `Do not show again` action to the message and the user can opt in not to show this again.

so there might be hope.